Ajax returning 500 error (Internal Server Error) in .NET Core project
I had an ASP.NET MVC web project in .NET framework 4.8 and refactored it to .NET 8.0 and onion architecture (UI is MVC). I have an uploader for uploading multiple files. In previous project, the uploader was working fine, but in the new version, it returns a http 500 error with no reason!
Here is view file as index.cshtml and scripts are like this:
$('form').submit(function (e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var files = $('form #uploadinput').files;
    
    var formData = new FormData();
    for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
        formData.append("files", files[i]);
    }

    var token = $('form input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/Uploader/UploadFiles',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        headers: {
            "X-XSRF-TOKEN": token
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data){
            ...
        },
        error: function (e){
            console.log(e.responseText); // in my situation it is empty string!
            console.log(e.status); // 500
        }
    )};
)};

In program.cs I defined X-XSRF-TOKEN:
...
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options=> options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
...

This is my UploadController (I didn't use newtonsoft package for json):
public class UploaderController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IUploaderService _uploaderService;

    public UploaderController (IUploaderService uploaderService)
    {
        _uploaderService = uploaderService;    
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles(IEnumerable<IFormFile> files, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...
        List<filesViewModel> response = await _uploaderService.DOSOMTHING();
        ...

        return Json(Ok(response)); // or return Json(response); or JsonReslut(response);
    }
}

The error appears in development mode - not in production.
The files are saved in the wwwroot/uploads folder and everything is still right.
The error occurred after controller returns model to view, in browser Console (DevTools) e.responseText is empty.
I tried to change Ajax and removed "headers" but it had no effect.
I also tried to upload multiple files and process them one by one, but Ajax still returns a http 500 after controller is trying to return model to view.

@PeterB This mistake just happened now and i fixed it. But I know this is not the problem

You should run this project in Visual Studio in a Debugging session (use the F5 button). It will then break on the error and then you can see the error details. We need to see the error details, and the exact line of code where it happens; without that it is impossible to help,
